# Bold font weight shifting text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have labels aligned in three rows and displayed in regular text. I'd like to make these labels **bold**, but when I apply the property in CSS, the alignment gets a little messed up.

I have included some padding and margin properties to have more space between text box and label, but that doesn't seem to help.

I am trying to have the text bold with "*" and have it aligned with "Surname" label.

How can I make the labels bold and still keep the alignment? I can only make changes to the CSS file and not HTML or font size of the text.

```
Before
```

[image]

```
After
```

[image]

```
**Before code-** 
.bold-label {
}

.bold-label:after {
color: #e32;
content: ' *';
display:inline; 
}

**After code-**
.bold-label {
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -1em;
padding-right: 0.75em;
}

.bold-label:after {
color: #e32;
content: ' *';
display:inline; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use: **text-align: right ;**

Comment: @ArifBurhan the text is already set to align right in a different property for that label. So, it didn't help. Hence. it is aligned when the labels are not bold.

Comment: @callMeJava text-align doesn't work on inline elements. It must be applied to a block level element that contains the elements that need to be aligned.

Comment: @teefars Your suggestion won't scale properly across different viewports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's the problem you're having:*

Each label box (`.bold-label`) is the width of its content (the text). This means that when the content expands (because you make it **bold**), the box will expand with it. This breaks your alignment.

To overcome this you could assign a width to each label box. With a large enough set width you can create enough space for the text to expand without changing the length of the box.

Try this:

```
.bold-label {
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: right; /* only works on block containers */
     width: 150px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nLzucuka/2/)

Comment: This is somewhat correct, but widths should not be set to absolute sizes. Relative sizes create a responsive design. min-width and max-width can be used to  prevent runaway sizes. But, even still, the real issue is that the text in the labels should be right-aligned.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ScottMarcus, your views on fixed widths I think are debatable, but I'm not disputing them. You're correct about the right-aligning. Except `text-align` only applies to block containers so the `display` value had to be changed, as well. Thanks.

Comment: I already pointed out that text-align only works on block level elements. I just didn't repeat that in the above comment. As for fixed-widths, you are welcome to your opinion, but building mobile-first with responsive design is not really just my opinion, it's really the current best practice for web development.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I hadn't noticed that you posted in the comments. And your answer wasn't clear, but you did mention using a `div`. Missed that. +1

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to have the labels that need to be right aligned (above Surname) in a container element, like a `div` and apply `text-align: right` to that container.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, but it puts the bullet-points on the left.  Hope it is of help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        li{
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:right;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <li>Consultation
    </li>

    <li>Pharmacist
    </li>

    <li>Registration No.
    </li>   
</body>
```