# is it possible to have html list with dots on right?

Tags: css, html4

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        li {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <li>Consultation</li>
    <li>Pharmacist</li>
    <li>Registration No.</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the bullet-points appear to the left of the list items ;

Can I make the dots go on the right ?

Comment: Following on from : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735758/bold-font-weight-shifting-text-alignment/35736003#35736003**

Comment: [`direction: rtl;`](https://jsfiddle.net/tyew2s8f/)

Comment: What dots? Do you mean the markers/bullets?

Comment: Incidentally your HTML is invalid; the `<li>` elements need to be wrapped in either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element.

Answer (score 3):

i) `direction:rtl;` should do the trick, since you have added `text-align:right` to the `li`, the `li` is **right** aligned. play around and you will be able to use it to suit your needs

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yv3ud/5/)**

**CSS:**

```
li{
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:right;
            direction:rtl;}
```

ii) In case if you are looking to add "*" required symbol next to each item like the one you mentioned in the url. You can do the below.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V88UY/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
li {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
}
li:after {
      content:"*";
}
```

iii) Or you can set the `list-style-type:none` and set background image for the bullet like in this example: **[Background images for bullet](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/08.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

Use `direction: rtl;` to make text and list item bullets orient right-to-left.

```
li {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyew2s8f/

**More Reading**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction
- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup

Answer (score 1):

You can use `direction: rtl;`. The direction property specifies the text direction/writing direction.

Tip: Use this property together with the unicode-bidi property to set or return whether the text should be overridden to support multiple languages in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bullet-points to the right but with text align left

```css
li {
  display:block;
  list-style:none;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

li::after {
    content: "•";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Consultation</li>
  <li>Pharmacist</li>
  <li>Registration No.</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that you could do.

```
`<style>
li {
list-style-type:none;
}
</style>`
```

^ That will get rid of the bullets

then manually add in • inside of your li tag

for example `<li>Consultation •</li>`

Comment: You should use an  `::after` pseudo-element instead of inserting `•` in the HTML.